# Windows 7 cannot get C/H/S values

Tags: windows-7, windows, grub, solaris

Alright, so I'm a bit of a novice at this kind of stuff, but I had a CD version of Solaris and decided to install it on the disk it came on. I put it into my Windows 7 computer and did all that stuff to the disk, but now when I try to boot the computer it comes up with a GRUB screen asking me to select between Windows and Solaris. When I do hit Windows it tells me an error about hd1 and it can't get C/H/S values. When I hit Solaris, the Solaris system works just fine. I'm pretty sure I don't have the install disk anymore, and the only reason I can even get on the internet is because of my MacBook pro laptop where I do all my other work. I have no idea what to do, and have thousands of irreplaceable files on that computer.

Comment: Your files most likely haven't gone anywhere, and you can always pull them out using a Linux LiveCD/USB if the file system's not corrupted (I'm sure there are NTFS drivers for Solaris as well). Perhaps you can try repairing the Windows bootloader using [the DVD](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft), and if you're able to successfully boot into Windows then you can restore Grub to get your dual boot up and running again.

Comment: I just found an install disk for Windows XP, would that do anything? I 'm getting a pre-formatted .iso of Windows 7, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Burn the ISO to a DVD or [transfer it to USB](http://wudt.codeplex.com), then boot from it and [run Startup Repair](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html).

Comment: I'd advise you to try it out first and report back with the results. I'm off for the day now but will check back later. If it works I'll gladly add it as an answer, else we'll see what else can be done depending on any error messages thrown.

Comment: Alright, well I am getting an error. Sort of. When I boot it from the disk, all I get is three or four blank lines, and the underscore cursor flashing. I've tried it from a USB and a CD, both with the .ISO extracted and not.

Comment: Did you burn the ISO as-is to a DVD (as in when you open the DVD in Explorer you see the .ISO)? That won't work. Neither will extracting and burning the contents, nor will extracting the contents to a USB stick. That's why I linked to the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool above, that transfers the ISO's contents to a USB drive *and* most importantly, makes it bootable. If you want to use a DVD, you'll need to use a program (such as [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/help/doku.php)) that will burn the ISO image correctly to create a bootable disc.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I guess this is the same problem as described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/376855/dual-booting-unix-from-dev-sdb .